# Can PREVRANDAO be written as a random number on chain?

Tags: randomness, randao

When Ethereum became 2.0, the block difficulty was changed to PREVRANDAO by EIP-4399.
We know that PREVRANDAO is a smart contract feature that generates a random number called RANDAO, which is used by the Ethereum protocol. Is it okay to use this to generate random numbers on-chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PREVRANDAO doesn't generate a new random number itself. For secure and unbiased random number generation on-chain, it's advisable to use external oracles, verifiable off-chain computations, or cryptographic methods that are less susceptible to manipulation.  There are various cryptographic techniques, like commit-reveal schemes, VRFs (Verifiable Random Functions), oracles that provide randomness, which can be used to generate random numbers for smart contracts in a more secure and reliable manner.

Answer (score 0):

`PREVRANDAO` opcode - [former `DIFFICULTY` opcode](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4399) - does not generate a new random number; it reads the [RANDAO mix generated in the previous block](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#randao).

If your application can work with a random number that is well-known before sending the transaction, then you can use that value in your smart contract.

If you expect the value to be unknown to the sender, then the PREVRANDAO operation is useless.

Please also consider the security implications of this opcode provided by [EIP-4399](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4399), particularly about biasability and predictability.